# how to minify js produced by sbt-concat

Tags: playframework-2.3, sbt-web, sbt-concat

I was doing my experiments using sbt-concat to combine css/js bundles.  I then tried to expand my pipeline in order to do minify for my css and js.  It is fairly easy to use sbt-css-compress which does minification of all the CSS produced by sbt-concat.
I tried sbt-closure for js, but it does not seem to work.  Just to be clear, I tried sbt-closure and it is confirmed that it does compilation of all js below to /assets.  However I am trying to figure out if it works with sbt-concat.

For example:
if I have /assets/js/f1.js and /assets/js/f2.js and I would like to combine them and minify into 1 bundle file.

Comment: It's generally the polite thing to do to accept an answer which suited your needs.

Answer (score 5):

You can use sbt-uglify to combine and minify.

Add to `plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-uglify" % "1.0.3")
```

Add to `build.sbt`:

```
pipelineStages := Seq(uglify)

UglifyKeys.uglifyOps := { js =>
  Seq((js.sortBy(_._2), "main.min.js"))
}
```

This will combine your javascript sources alphabetically by their file path.

Use `pipelineStages in Assets` if you want to concat/uglify in development. Normally it would only execute for a production build.

Answer (score 2):

One way that I know is to do the concat in 'pipelineStages in Assests' and include a filter

For example in `build.sbt`

```
Concat.groups := Seq(
  "all.js" -> group(Seq(
    "js/f1.js",
    "js/f2.js"
  ))
)

Concat.parentDir := "concated"

Closure.suffix := ".min.js"

Closure.flags := Seq("--formatting=PRETTY_PRINT", "--accept_const_keyword")

pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(concat)

includeFilter in closure := "all.js"

pipelineStages := Seq(closure, digest, gzip)
```

Comment: Did you mean to redefine `pipelineStages`?

Comment: Ah, I see that the first one is in `pipelineStages in Assets`. But that doesn't quite clarify why that is.